# No body information available (imap-fetchstructure)

Tags: php, imap, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer-BMH class to run through mailboxes to sort bounces. The script has been running fine for months, but all of a sudden, I keep getting the same error.

The error occurs on this line:

```
if($structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->_mailbox_link, $x))
```

Obviously, $x is the e-mail number in the mailbox. Checked it, all good.

The returned error is:
**Warning**:  imap_fetchstructure() [function.imap-fetchstructure]: No body information available in **--path--/PHPMailer-BMH/class.phpmailer-bmh.php** on line **xxx**

The absurd part is that the script runs fine for all other mailboxes.

The even worst part: the script runs through about 150-200 e-mails fine on this same mailbox, then outputs this warning for the rest. They don't get processed.

I've checked, the e-mails do have content and headers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the IMAP server's logs will provide some insight?

Comment: I see LOGIN and LOGOUT lines a few times around that time, then a TIMEOUT further down, I'm guessing when it loads all messages. However I don't get how there could be timeout error when it's been running well before with many more e-mails than that.

FYI script and e-mails are on the same server.

Comment: So I did further tests by adding imap_ping (to keep the connection alive and prevent timeout), but that doesn't change anything to the result... I will keep on trying to find a solution, but any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which kind of IMAP server are you using, and which version of PHP?

Comment: PHP 5.3.4, it's a Linux server, and even though I'm not sure this answers your question, it's imapd.

Comment: Have you already tried to set the `use_fetchstructure` property to false? For example: `$bmh = new BounceMailHandler(); $bmh->use_fetchstructure = false;`. This way the message type should be detected directly from headers, without calling the `imap_fetchstructure` function. Also, how did you set the `disable_delete` and `purge_unprocessed` properties?

Comment: Well, the part I modified further down in the script uses imap_fetchstructure a anyways. When I disabled the use of this function, the alternative worked fine; but I actually need imap_fetchstructure to work as I am scanning all messages for spacific headers, and they are sometimes returned as an attachment, sometimes in the content, we can never know... Both other parameters are set to false (processed messages are deleted, and we keep unknowns for creating new rules)

Comment: Were you able to determine if the problem always starts at the same  `$x` value?

Comment: Yes, I thought I had said this previously but apparently not, sorry. However, it is not always the same e-mail message (old unknown messages are deleted after a specific amount of days).